# Angular JS - Preventing a controller from running

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, angularjs-controller

So I'm doing a simple 'is the user logged in' check and redirecting the user to the signin.html page if they are not logged in. My code looks something like this:

```
var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies']);

myAppModule.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when('/page2', {
    controller:'pagetwo',
    templateUrl:'pagetwo.html'
})
.when('/signin', {
    controller:'signinCTRL',
    templateUrl:'signin.html'
})

});

myAppModule.run(function($rootScope, userInfo, $location) {
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
    myCurrentRoute = $location.$$path;

    if(myCurrentRoute != "/signin") {
        userInfo.checkLogin(); //  Check login first. This has the $location.path( "/signin" ); in it.
    }
})

});
```

My problem is that when a user goes to /page2, the $routeChangeSuccess function fires fine and inside the userInfo.checkLogin() I redirect them to a new route that redirects them on the signin.html page.

The problem is that *the pagetwo controller still fires before the user is redirected to the signinCTRL controller*.

**Is there a way to prevent the pagetwo controller from running somehow?** I know I could probably just wrap everything in the signinCTRL to check if the user is logged in, but that defeats the purpose of having the routeChangeSuccess function.

Comment: Curious why you are doing this client side.  If the user navigates to a page that they are not authorized to view, you should have the server return a 403 error.  Then you can catch that and redirect to a login page.

Comment: @BenFelda - Really, all the real user authentication happens on the server side via PHP. It's impossible for the JS to call pages/files/data without having an authorized php session. I'm only concerned about throwing errors that don't need to happen. This particular project is also a learning experience for me using Angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of watching for the `$routeChangeSuccess` you can watch for the [`$locationChangeStart`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24location) event.

`$locationChangeStart` is fired before the controller is called.

You can read more about the differences between `$locationChangeStart` and `$routeChangeStart` in this blog on [how to cancel route navigation in angular](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2013/11/07/cancelling-route-navigation-in-angularjs-controllers.aspx)

[demo plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/peIgomSJ2x2uUoTxuhGj?p=preview) using `$locationChangeStart`

Answer (score 0):

I have dealt with this very issue where the login feature was handled by a servlet outside of my angular js application.

I controlled access to the application through a javax.servlet.Filter

and I also had another Filter that I used on all Json requests coming from the application.

For the unauthenticated user scenario the Json filter behaved as follows;

```
 httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED); //401
```

I added a $rootScope method that forced login for any 401 response from a JSON controller.

```
   $rootScope.handleHttpFailure = function(data,status) {
        if (401 == status) {
            document.location.reload(true);
        }  else {
            console.log("post ERROR status:" + status + " response:" + data);
            $rootScope.alert('Error received status:'+ status + " response:" + data );
        }
    }
```

So for your scenario, you can't prevent the pagetwo controller from running but you can prevent it from accessing secured resources if you follow this fairly simple pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Listening to  `$routeChangeStart` instead of the `$routeChangeSuccess` event might solve your problem in the short term. You can also do the login check in a one of the route `resolve` map promises and just return a promise dismiss for a login failure. then listening to the $routeChangeError could navigate for the `signin` url or just navigate to it from the resolve promise.

for a more complete and rubust routing solution you should probably use [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), the router any serious angular app should use (and is rumored to enter angular core in the future).

Yes, you should **also** validate correct login and authorization on the server side and return a 401 response in case It's invalid (then you can use the wonderful [http auth interceptor](https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth) to handle errors. But I disagree with the notion you should do it **only** server side, this is prone to lousy user exprience and you should certainly do the basic tests in the client side

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the best way to handle the error and works nicely**

```
function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
    var interceptor = [
        '$rootScope', '$q', function (scope, $q) {

            function success(response) {
                return response;
            }

            function error(response) {
                var status = response.status;

                if (status == 401) {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    var req = {
                        config: response.config,
                        deferred: deferred
                    };
                    window.location = "/";
                }

                if (status == 404) {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    var req = {
                        config: response.config,
                        deferred: deferred
                    };
                    window.location = "#/404";
                }
                // otherwise
                //return $q.reject(response);
                window.location = "#/500";
            }

            return function (promise) {
                return promise.then(success, error);
            };

        }
    ];
    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(interceptor);
});

// routes
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/404', {
            templateUrl: '/app/html/inserts/error404.html',
            controller: 'RouteCtrl'
        })
        .when('/500', {
            templateUrl: '/app/html/inserts/error404.html',
            controller: 'RouteCtrl'
        })

        ......

   };
```